# Modular arithmetic and semi elgamal encryption

Tags: cryptography, number-theory, elgamal

I'm implementing a semi ELGamal cryptosystem(from a [research paper](http://www.win.tue.nl/~berry/papers/crypto99.pdf)) function that has been used in PVSS. Unfortunately, I fail to decrypt as it has been described in the algorithm.

Here is the initialisation phase:

Select a secure prime p such that p-1=2q where q is also a prime, then make a cyclic group G and let g be a random generator of this group. Pick a random x(private key) in the group and let y = g^x(public key). I simply initialise the algorithm as following:

```
p = 233;
g = 131;
x = 139;
y = g ^ x mod 233; //y = 182
```

Now let s (secret) be 23 and we compute our es (encrypted secret):

```
s = 23
es = y ^ s mod 233// es = 231
```

In order to decrypt the es, I raise es to the inverse of x(private key), I should return the g ^ s, assume ds is the deciphered value:

```
ds = es ^ 1/x mod 233 // 1/x = 57, ds = 116
```

Problem is here, ds is not equal to g ^ s but in theory it should be because:

recall that we encrypted our s as:

```
es = y ^ s mod 233
```

and we know that

```
y = g ^ x mod 233
```

so,

```
es = g ^ x ^ s mod 233
```

Given that,

```
ds = es ^ 1/x mod 233
// which means:
ds = g ^ x ^ s ^ 1/x mod 233
```

therefore, I expect to get same result as of g^s  (131 ^ 23 mod 233) which must be 182 while what I get as the ds result is 116.

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: What order does the group have (*p* or *q* or something else)? If it is supposed to be *q*, then you have a problem, because *q* is not prime. Are you sure 131 is a generator of the group? How do you calculate `1/x`?

Comment: Where is the programming part of your question? If you don't have one, [Crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) might be a much better place for this question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. the group has the order of p. I'm using NTL for modular arithmetic and have double checked all values using online modulo calculators. Maybe I give it a try on Crypto forum or edit my question with source code as you suggested. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have:

```
x * invX = 1 mod p
```

the following equality is generally not true:

```
(g ^ x) ^ invX = g mod p
```

Above expression means multiplying `g*g*....*g` a certain number of times, `x * invX`, which is also `k * p + 1` according to first modulo relation.

Say your generator has a size `n <= p-1`:

```
g ^ n = 1 mod p
```

That means that `x * invX` must be a multiple of `n`...

In your preamble, you assert that `q=(p-1)/2` is prime, but here, it's not the case, `q=116`...

And in your example g=131 is generating a sequence of length 58=(p-1)/4.
Then, only those x have the property `g ^ x ^(1/x) = 1 mod p` :

```
58 116 132 154 174 203 229 231 232
```

Note that for another generator, g=5, the sequence is of maximal length p-1, and then the sole x satisfying `(g ^ x) ^ invX = 1 mod p` is `x=p-1`.

Since `y^(p-1) = 1 mod p` for any y non multiple of p, x=p-1 is allways working as you expect anyway...

Comment: thanks for your answer. My bad you are right, the p was wrong. Still, I did not fully understand the sequence being of maximal length p-1. However, I tried with new inputs such as p=263 and g=2 (we know that 2 must be always be a generator for a secure prime) still I'm failing to get the correct result. Can you gimme another hint what is exactly wrong with my assumptions and how should I do it correctly?

Comment: @mersad00 `p = 263` should work, because it has prime order 131 (*q*). This means that *x* and *s* must be smaller that the order of the group.

Comment: @mersad00 why n<=p-1? There are at most p different values modulo p, right? And it's difficult to generate 0, unless gcd(g,p) > 1.

Comment: @mersad00 as for a hint, try to multiply (g^x)^(p-s) and (g^x)^s modulo p, and compare to (g^x)